# Why are callout labels being double counted on my stacked bar chart?

Tags: labeling, charts

See below:

> [image]

The problem is that the "leftist" labels are being counted twice on the right stacked bar. How to fix this?

Comment: Please, please, please do not post images of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug.

Fake data to replicate the issue:

```
data = {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>, <|"x" -> 5, "y" -> 2, "z" -> 3|>};

BarChart[data, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ChartLabels -> Callout[Automatic, Automatic]]
```

[image]

Same issue with default layout:

```
BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> Callout[Automatic, Automatic]]
```

[image]

**A work-around:** wrap `Callout` on input data using `KeyValueMap[Callout[#2, #]&]`:

```
BarChart[KeyValueMap[Callout[#2, #]&] /@ data, ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

[image]

```
BarChart[KeyValueMap[Callout[#2, #]&] /@ data]
```

[image]

**Update:** It gets weirder with additional data sets:

```
data2 = {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>, 
   <|"x" -> 5, "y" -> 2, "z" -> 3|>,  <|"u" -> 5, "v" -> 2|>, <||>};

BarChart[data2, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartLabels -> Callout[Automatic, Automatic]]
```

[image]

We need to delete empty `Association`s before applying the work-around:

```
BarChart[KeyValueMap[Callout[#2, #] &] /@ 
  DeleteCases[data2, Association[]], ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

[image]

It seems that the issue is not limited to `Callout`s either:

```
BarChart[data2, ChartLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
BarChart[KeyValueMap[Labeled[#2, #] &] /@ DeleteCases[data2, Association[]]]
```

[image]

Comment: I assume these are bugs in Mathematica?

Comment: @George, they sure are. You might  want to report to WRI.

Comment: Note that it's assumed in BarChart that all the bars of a particular color are the "same" in some way.  In general with associations, the later ones are taken to have all the keys seen previously, even if they're missing.

Comment: Brett, is there a reason for accumulation of keys?